# exception exit: "cannot load yaws"

Tags: erlang, ubuntu-14.04, yaws

I have been trying to embed yaws into an erlang application but no matter what I do I get this exception thrown out

```
** exception exit: "cannot load yaws"
     in function  yaws_api:embedded_start_conf/4 (yaws_api.erl, line 2598)
     in call from ybed:run/0 (ybed.erl, line 35)
3>
```

I used yaws sample "ybed.erl" example but there is still no luck:  http://hyber.org/code.yaws?file=/ybed.erl

I am using ubuntu 14.04

## Update

As suggested by **Steve Vinoski**,It was a load path issue.

I included `application:load(yaws)` as instructed and the return value was `{error,{"no such file or directory","yaws.app"}}`. so I ran Erlang follows `$ sudo erl -pa /usr/lib/yaws/ebin` and it worked like charm.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a load path issue, since the failure is caused by a call to `application:load(yaws)` failing inside `yaws_api:embedded_start_conf/4`. I don't know how you're creating or starting your application, but you need to make sure the `yaws` application is in the load path.

To fully answer your question, we need to know why `application:load(yaws)` is failing. Temporarily change your copy of `ybed.erl` to call `application:load(yaws)` just before the call to `yaws_api:embedded_start_conf/4`, and see what `application:load/1` returns. This will give you an indication of why the `application:load/1` call inside `yaws_api:embedded_start_conf/4` is failing.